# Most suitable image format for email footers, considering : image quality, text legibility, file size, compatibility?

Tags: file-format, e-mail

I want to put an image in my email footer which will contain company logo, some text, some awards ive won etc..

I want to place this in as a graphic, so it renders the same on all devices, rather than an html footer block containing a mixture of text and images.

What is the best image format to go for considering (in no particular order) : image quality, text legibility, file size, compatibility ?

Comment: Don't do it. It adds unnecessary file size to emails unless it is *specifically* a sales email. And if it is *not* a sales email.. then it'll merely annoy anyone receiving plain text email, since it'll always be an attachment.

Comment: I know on MacOS / OSX, in the native email client Mac Mail you can place images inline, im not sure if Outlook / Gmail / Others would render it inline also ?

Comment: You can't control users clients.. remember there are a million different phones and devices as well as email clients. My point is you will **never** know exactly how an email is received by most people. If the nature of the emails is *communication* and not "sales", then merely format a nice text-only email signature. Don't add images. Images are for *sales* emails. Just FYI.. I'm a life-long Mac user.. but I don't use Apple's email application.. your "signature image" would appear as an attachment in each and every email you sent me.

Comment: Bear in mind that in contexts such as high-dpi (e.g. Retina) display, even if it loads (my phone email client does not load images by default), it may be scaled up quite a bit and not look good. So you wind up needing to make a larger image and then wrapping in html to set the size.

Answer (score 1):

Focusing only in image formats, the answer is the same as any web page.

- PNG if the images have a flat design.
- JPG if you have a photo.
- Or simply try the other format and see which one weighs less on your specific case.

The "awards" part sounds not that good to me. Put that on the webpage, not in the email footer. Keep the design clean with relevant contact information.

The "legibility" is a design issue, not a file format issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify about file formats:

.png accommodates transparency and is typically a larger file. A photo with a transparent background (like a cutout) would show transparency in .png only.

.jpg is for graphics and photos with no transparency

A good general rule of thumb is use .jpg at 150px and you'll cover most displays. You optimize for art sampling or text based on what's predominant.

As has already been mentioned, footers with more than basic information will not only not get read, loading a graphic is going to bloat the newsletter size and not even show up for many recipients based on the many variables already mentioned.